# How to traverse through map inside map in java

Tags: java

I am new to Java.

I have a map like this.

```
HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>mp;
```

How to traverse through this?

mp has another inside it.

I know the normal way of traversing through the map using entrySet;

Answer (score 4):

You traverse the outer map using entrySet, then for each value of the outer map you traverse the inner map using entrySet.

```
for (Map.Entry<String,HashMap<String,String>> entry : mp.entrySet()) {
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> innerEntry : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `entry.getValue()` -> `entry.getValue().entrySet()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>mp= new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();
      HashMap<String, String> innerMap1= new HashMap<String, String>();
      innerMap1.put("1", "firstValueOf_InnerMap1");
      innerMap1.put("2", "SecondValueOf_InnerMap1");

      HashMap<String, String> innerMap2= new HashMap<String, String>();
      innerMap2.put("1", "firstValueOf_InnerMap2");
      innerMap2.put("2", "SecondValueOf_InnerMap2");

      mp.put("one", innerMap1);
      mp.put("two", innerMap2);

          for (HashMap<String,String> innerHashMap : mp.values()) {
              for (String value : innerHashMap.values()) {
                 System.out.println(value);
              }
          }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Set hmset = hm.entrySet();
for (HashMap<String,String> innerMap : hm.values()) {
    for (String st1 : innerMap.values()) {
       System.out.println(st1);
    }
}
```